# qTip2 tooltip on FullCalendar shows tooltips below calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, tooltip, qtip2

I have used qTip2 for tooltips. It works as I hover over the events in FullCalendar but it shows the tooltips below the calendar. What might cause the tooltips to show up below the calendar not inside the calendar?

My code is shown below:

```
eventRender(event, element, view) {

     console.log(event, element, view);
     element.qtip({
       prerender:true,
           content:{
             text:'<h4>'+event.title+'</h4>',
           position:{
             my:"top center",
             at:"bottom ccenter",

           },

        },

     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of qtip, you can use tooltip (if youre using bootstrap)

```
var tooltip =  event.title;
$(element).attr("data-original-title", tooltip)
$(element).tooltip({ container: "body" })
```

Comment: it works but cant use third line code ({container:"body"}) it shows error on using this. without using it works fine but the tooltip positons goes outside the calendar div for events which are or extreme left or right. any tips or suggestions for how to fix that.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function this error shows up on taking $(element).tooltip({ container: "body" }). without this, tooltips move outside the calendar boundaries for events whoich are on extreme left or right. I wa nt to be inside the calendar.